# How would I display all elements in an array in HTML as clickable objects?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, cordova

So I have produced a small script in javascript as shown:

```
var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
txtFile.open("GET", "http://www.drakedesign.co.uk/mdmarketing/uploads/date.txt", true);
txtFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (txtFile.readyState === 4) {  // Makes sure the document is ready to parse.
        if( (txtFile.status == 200) || (txtFile.status == 0) ) { // Makes sure it's found the file.
            allText = txtFile.responseText;
            arrayOfLines = allText.match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
            document.getElementById("date").innerHTML =  arrayOfLines[0];
            filename1 = (arrayOfLines[0] + ".csv");
            res1 = filename1.replace("/","-");
            res2 = res1.replace("/","-");
            urlCsv = ("http://www.drakedesign.co.uk/mdmarketing/uploads/" + res2);

        }
    }
};

txtFile.send(null);
```

The above code simple parses a text document which is updated weekly: http://www.drakedesign.co.uk/mdmarketing/uploads/date.txt

which has dates within it written line by line like so:

16/04/16

09/04/16

02/04/16...

I am here to ask how would I convert my above script to parse the text document and then display each element in the html document and making the visual element clickable so that it would take me to the correct date.

Am I going about this the wrong way? is there a much more efficient way to do it? I am at this point considering hard coding for all the possible dates that could appear. But I would much rather do this dynamically!

Thank you very much in advance to anyone who offers help.

PS: I AM USING JQUERY! Sorry forgot to mention before.

Comment: Once you receive the date.txt file with the dates, you want to create links for each date like this? <a href="#">16/04/16</a>, but where do you want the links to go? Will jQuery.get() function help make things easier for you? https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: are you familiar with the jQuery library? Sounds like you might be relatively new to JavaScript so I thought I'd mention it - if you're ok with using jQuery you will get different answers than if you're not ok with using jQuery. If you don't care either way, that might be worth stating.

Comment: Hey there I am using jquery i forgot to mention! yes I am relatively new but this issue really had me stuck, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't include the `jQuery` tag in your question so I'm going to assume you're looking for a plain Javascript answer.  For each date that you receive in your response, you can turn it into a `link`, which will be clickable on your page.

Something like this:

```
function createLink(text, url, parentElement) {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  var linkText = document.createTextNode(text);
  a.appendChild(linkText);
  a.href = url;
  parentElement.appendChild(a);
}
```

Then you can use this helper to create as many links as you like:

```
createLink('16/04/16', 'http://www.hello.com/16/04/16', document.body);
```

Comment: Sorry I do have Jquery imported. Forgot to  say

Comment: I also think you completely solved my issue in about two seconds! let me implement it and get back to you with a big tick and a +1

Comment: By the "Parent Element" are you referring to the div id?

Comment: @JamesMallon no, I'm referring to the actual DOM element, such as a the `body`.  If you like, you can change the `createLink` function's last argument to accept an id and replace the last line with `document.getElementById(id).appendChild(a)`.  Hope that helps!